# Why does Lucene fail to match this string with a unicode character?

Tags: java, regex, lucene

I'm using Lucene to perform a search but it is failing to match a word with a unicode character in it. Here's a brief test:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

import org.apache.lucene.index.Term;
import org.apache.lucene.search.regex.RegexQuery;
import org.junit.Test;

public class ReturnUnicodeTest {

    @Test
    public void testQueryWithUnicodeChar() {

        // zero to many non-whitespace followed by zero to many whitespace chars
        Term mustTerm = new Term("FieldName", "Áuto" + "[^\\s]*(\\s*)");
        RegexQuery mustTermQuery = new RegexQuery(mustTerm);


        mustTermQuery.getRegexImplementation().compile("Áuto" + "[^\\s]*(\\s*)");
        boolean match = mustTermQuery.getRegexImplementation().match("Test Áutomotive");
        assertTrue(match);
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if this is a setting of my implementation of Lucene or a limitation of RegexQuery or something else. What are some possible reasons this does not work?

Comment: In Lucene, a full string match is expected, so try `.*Áuto.*`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That's a good suggestion, I will see if that works within our implementation, the unit test passes with that for sure.

Comment: Add how the index is created... which analyzer are you using? Because by default whitespace is NOT indexed.